How do I switch from OAuth to API keys in a Cloudbeds Marketplace app?
I'm using OAuth to get authentication tokens for my marketplace app in Cloudbeds and would like to switch to use API Keys without having to have my customers reconnect to my app in the marketplace.  Is that possible?

You can call the access_token API with grant type = "refresh_token_exchange".   This is the same as the call you are already doing today to refresh the auth token, only the grant_type changes - the client id, client secret & refresh token parameters remain the same.  The response will have the api key as the access_token value which you can start using, however once you've done this you can't refresh the oauth token again otherwise it will break the API key.
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.cloudbeds.com/api/v1.2/access_token' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data-urlencode 'grant_type=refresh_token_exchange' \
  --data-urlencode 'client_id=brian_xxxxx' \
  --data-urlencode 'client_secret=123456abcd' \
  --data-urlencode 'refresh_token=0987654edcba'

and the response looks like:
{
    "access_token": "cbat_xyz123",
    "refresh_token": "",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 0,
    "resources": []
}

